# how to change elements of a data frame based on another dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, bigdata

I have a big data `df`. and I have another csv file `dg`. The `dg` data frame has been made from `df` by the following code:

```
dg=df.groupBy('title).count().orderBy('count')
```

I attached a new column to `dg` it is called `new`. I want to make an new column and go through all rows of `df`, if `title` in df is equal `title` in `dg` change it by `new`. for an example suppose:

```
title  
summer
apple
hi
hi
apple


title    new
summer   AH
apple    now
hi       good
```

output:

```
 title  new 
summer  AH
apple   now
hi      good
hi      good
apple   now
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve and the example you include is not clear (e.g. you write that you've got counts in your `dg` and yet none of the examples include numbers), but are you looking for `pandas.merge()`? You can specify an `inner` join in there. Or is your big data too big to use  `pandas`?

Comment: it has millions rows, too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `left join` should do.

```
df.join(dg, ['title'], "left").show()

+------+----+
| title| new|
+------+----+
|summer|  AH|
| apple| now|
|    hi|good|
|    hi|good|
| apple| now|
+------+----+
```

Comment: it is not a pandas data frame

Comment: Use `distinct()` for removing duplicates: `df.join(dg, ['title'],"left").distinct().show()`. The solution above works for you what you posted. Please update the question with clear examples if you still have problems.